How to send the proof that is built by using bellman crate to the Solana program?
Now I am working with a ZKP project. And this requires that all of the code have to be done by using Rust. So ZKP have to be generated by using Rust and also verified in Solana program.
I am going to use the bellman or arkworks with groth16-solana but it is not working. Because the proof that is built by using bellman or arkworks can not be integrated with groth16-solana.
Writing all of the code by using Rust is must.
How to solve this problem?
